# How can I fix layout issues on an animated banner within the CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm making a practice website to improve my coding skills and I have been trying to make a scrolling image banner. Whilst I have got the banner to work when I try to add a border the border doesn't go round the entire object.

I've made the layout and animation of the banner in the CSS and have had no problems other than at the end of the banner there is a 4/5 second cut out before the banner continues.

I just tried adding a border in the CSS of the banner where the size is defined but it caused the above problem. I have included a screenshot of the CSS for the banner below (not including the animation CSS).

**Error:**

[image]

**CSS:**

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the `transform` property applied to image. When scaled, the image will overlay its parent (since it gets its own layer-context):

```css
div {
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid;
}

div img:hover {
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" alt=""></div>
```

You could solve this by placing the border around the `img` itself instead of parent:

```css
div {
  padding:1em;
}

div img {
  border:2px solid red;
}

div img:hover {
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" alt=""></div>
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the `scale` transform property and enlarge image by increasing its height/width for better control.

Comment: Thanks, this got the borders to work, with a little editing of images it will make the banner look better as a whole. I was just looking for a way to wrap the images and this worked perfectly

Comment: Welcome. Next time just copy paste the code directly instead of posting a screenshot of it ;-)